# Need to extract attributes directly from Avro using NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have found no way in NiFi to extract attributes directly from Avro so I am using ConvertAvroToJson -> EvaluateJsonPath -> ConvertJsonToAvro as the workaround.

But I would like to write a script to extract the attributes from the Avro flow file for use in an ExecuteScript processor to determine if it is a better approach.

Does anyone have a script to do this?  Otherwise, I may end up using the original approach.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Could you explain what you'd like to do after you extract the values?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Groovy script (which needs the Avro JAR in its Module Directory property) where I let the user specify dynamic properties with JSONPath expressions to be evaluated against the Avro file. Ironically it does a `GenericData.toString()` which converts the record to JSON anyway, but perhaps there is some code in here you could reuse:

```
import org.apache.avro.*
import org.apache.avro.generic.*
import org.apache.avro.file.*
import groovy.json.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

final GenericData genericData = GenericData.get();
slurper = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.INDEX_OVERLAY)

pathAttrs = this.binding?.variables?.findAll {attr -> attr.key.startsWith('avro.path')}
newAttrs = [:]
try {
   session.read(flowFile, { inputStream ->
   def reader = new DataFileStream<>(inputStream, new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>())
   GenericRecord currRecord = null;
   if(reader.hasNext()) {
       currRecord = reader.next();
       log.info(genericData.toString(currRecord))
       record = slurper.parseText(genericData.toString(currRecord))
       pathAttrs?.each {k,v ->
         object = record
         v.value.tokenize('.').each {
            object = object[it]
          }
          newAttrs[k - "avro.path."] = String.valueOf(object)
        }
        reader.close()
   }
} as InputStreamCallback)
newAttrs.each{k,v ->
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, k,v)
}
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
} catch(e) {
  log.error("Error during Avro Path: {}", [e.message] as Object[], e)
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
```

If you meant to extract Avro metadata vs fields (not totally sure what you meant by "attributes"), also check MergeContent's [AvroMerge](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/MergeContent.java#L886) as there is some code in there to pull Avro metadata:

Comment: Sorry, what is "AVRO JAr" do you mean ?

Comment: UPD:

`@Grab('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
@Grab('org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1')
import ....

Answer (score 0):

If you are extracting simple patterns from a single Avro record per flowfile, [`ExtractText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/index.html) may be sufficient for you. If you want to take advantage of the new record processing available in Apache NiFi 1.3.0, [`AvroReader`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroReader/index.html) is where you should start, and there are [a series](http://bryanbende.com/development/2017/06/20/apache-nifi-records-and-schema-registries) of [blogs](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) describing this [process](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/real-time-sql-on-event) in detail. You can also extract Avro metadata with [`ExtractAvroMetadata`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-avro-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.avro.ExtractAvroMetadata/index.html).